# SQL SUM and Count in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created two queries that both return the results I want individually but I need a single result set from the one query and I can't figure out how to merge the two.
I plan to use the output of the query as input to an insert statement to create a new record in a different table.

Whatever I try it ends up multiplying the TotalExpense by the number of lots.

I'm Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Any suggestions / solutions greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    sPortfolioName
    ,Count(lot.lLotID) as TotalLots

FROM [Owners]

inner join Portfolio on Portfolio.lUserID = Owners.lUserID
inner Join tblExpense on tblExpense.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
inner Join Lot on Lot.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID

where bManaged = 'Y' 
AND tblExpense.lExpenseCodeID = '5' 
Group By sPortfolioName 
Order By sPortfolioName


SELECT 
      Portfolio.sPortfolioName
      ,sum (tblExpense.mRate) as TotalExpense
  FROM [Owners]
  inner join Portfolio on Portfolio.lUserID = Owners.lUserID
  inner Join tblExpense on tblExpense.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
  where bManaged = 'Y' 
  AND tblExpense.lExpenseCodeID = '5' 
  Group By sPortfolioName
```

Current Results

```
sPortfolioName  TotalLots
Black           836
Blue            1107
Brown           22

sPortfolioName  TotalExpense
Black           393.90
Blue            17.83
Brown           511.00
```

Desired Result

```
sPortfolioName  TotalLots   TotalExpense
Black           836         393.90
Blue            1107        17.83
Brown           22          511.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries are almost same with same column used in `GROUP BY` clause, so you can combine them in single query having both aggregate functions `COUNT()` and `SUM()`

```
SELECT
    sPortfolioName
    ,Count(lot.lLotID) as TotalLots
    ,sum (tblExpense.mRate) as TotalExpense
FROM [Owners]

inner join Portfolio on Portfolio.lUserID = Owners.lUserID
inner Join tblExpense on tblExpense.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
inner Join Lot on Lot.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID

where bManaged = 'Y' 
AND tblExpense.lExpenseCodeID = '5' 
Group By sPortfolioName 
Order By sPortfolioName
```

**EDIT**

Try this and check if its returning correct desired result

```
SELECT t1.sPortfolioName, t1.TotalLots, t2.TotalExpense
FROM
(
SELECT
    sPortfolioName
    ,Count(lot.lLotID) as TotalLots

FROM [Owners]

inner join Portfolio on Portfolio.lUserID = Owners.lUserID
inner Join tblExpense on tblExpense.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
inner Join Lot on Lot.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID

where bManaged = 'Y' 
AND tblExpense.lExpenseCodeID = '5' 
Group By sPortfolioName
) As t1

INNER JOIN

(
  SELECT 
      Portfolio.sPortfolioName
      ,sum (tblExpense.mRate) as TotalExpense
  FROM [Owners]
  inner join Portfolio on Portfolio.lUserID = Owners.lUserID
  inner Join tblExpense on tblExpense.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
  where bManaged = 'Y' 
  AND tblExpense.lExpenseCodeID = '5' 
  Group By sPortfolioName
) As t2

ON t1.sPortfolioName = t2.sPortfolioName
ORDER BY t1.sPortfolioName
```

Comment: This didn't work it multiplied the TotalExpense by the number of lots.  Each owner has one expense and many lots.  I need a subtotal for each portfolio

Comment: check edit section answer above, i have used join between the two subqueries , each sub query returns the result and is combined using join based on `sPortfolioName` common column

Comment: That cracked it :)  I never think to join a select statement.  Thanks heaps you saved me having to come up with some lame insert then update statement.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is already an accepted answer, I just want to note that the query can be simplified. like so:

```
SELECT
    sPortfolioName
    ,Lot.TotalLots
    ,sum (tblExpense.mRate) as TotalExpense
FROM [Owners]
inner join Portfolio on Portfolio.lUserID = Owners.lUserID
inner Join tblExpense on tblExpense.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
inner Join (select lOwnersID, count(*) as TotalLots from Lot group by lOwnersID) Lot on Lot.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
where bManaged = 'Y' 
AND tblExpense.lExpenseCodeID = '5' 
Group By sPortfolioName 
Order By sPortfolioName
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
        SELECT
            Portfolio.sPortfolioName
            ,Count(lot.lLotID) as TotalLots
            ,sum (tblExpense.mRate) as TotalExpense

        FROM [Owners]

        inner join Portfolio on Portfolio.lUserID = Owners.lUserID
        inner Join tblExpense on tblExpense.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID
        inner Join Lot on Lot.lOwnersID = Owners.lOwnersID

        where bManaged = 'Y' 
        AND tblExpense.lExpenseCodeID = '5' 
        Group By sPortfolioName ,sPortfolioName
        Order By sPortfolioName
```

Comment: As I suspected this multiplied the TotalExpense by the number of lots.